# Converting minutes in numeric to Date time object in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with values in minutes

```
0 , 30 , 60 ... 1410
```

I need to cast them as

```
00:00:00, 00:30:00, 01:00:00 ... 23:30:00
```

How can I achieve this using R.

Thanks

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38202967/996366

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could try

```
sprintf("%d:%02d:00", v1%/%60, v1%%60)
#[1] "0:00:00"  "0:30:00"  "1:00:00"  "23:30:00"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(0, 30, 60, 1410)
```